# How to add Assembly Information to a Web Site/App in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vs-web-application-project, assemblyinfo

Can anyone tell me how to add an AssemblyInfo.vb file to a Web Application converted from NET2.0 to NET3.5.

I'd like to add the manifest information but cannot find a way to do for the Web Application's compiled DLL.

I am using Web Deployment Projects for Visual Studio 2008 if this makes a difference. I'm also going to be replacing the version number with the SVN build number but haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After further research it appears that there are problems with Web Deployment Projects and Web Application Projects when merging assemblies. The only way to get it work is to name the assemblies differently, which leaves me with 1 assembly with version information and 1 assembly with my manifest information (keeping in mind my version information comes from SVNLabeller).

This isn't what I want. So I'm now reverting to Web Site Projects and have discovered I can manually edit the .wdproj file to add extra Assembly Information, it's a shame I can't do it via Visual Studio but is the best solution I can come up with for now.